# Appendix C. - integration in Eclipse Mars.1

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I try to follow this tutorial:
http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-pde-integration.html
Unfortunately I don't know how to set Target Platform (paragraph "Select Spring Dynamic Modules Target Platform"), in my Eclipse this window looks very different than one in the tutorial.. Could you pleas help mi with that?

Comment: No. Unless you post a relevant snippet of the code that you have trouble with, formatted as a MCVE. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That isn't the standard Eclipse Target Platform dialog so I assume it must be something you get with the Spring IDE (which is based on Eclipse).

Comment: Is not that some old pre-Indigo interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have *.target file in one of imported projects. You [can find it](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html#tuturial_targetplatform_activate) in new target platform dialog too.